# Avoiding SQL Injections with Parameters by C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I have recently adjusted my code to avoid getting SQL injections for maria db and got helped with adding parameters ,when I using parameters method page got running time error

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from user where uid = @uid AND start >= @StartDate AND end <= @EndDate ";
DataSet ds = QueryDataSet(strSQL, uid , StartDate, EndDate);


public DataSet QueryDataSet(string strSQL,string uid , string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, DBconn);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uid );
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", EndDate);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    //catch
    {
        throw (new System.Exception(ex.Message));

    }
}
```

I am relatively new to using maria db so any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: @Michael How is this a duplicate?

Comment: TBH I don't know why this has been flagged, since there's not even a question to begin with ...

Comment: @ZoharPeled may have gotten a bit hammery, this is a duplicate though, or just a bad question. However i am out of votes for this question now

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm just wondering what makes you think that this is a duplicate of the question you've chosen. I mean, this isn't even a question - just a code dump - and clearly not about why to use parameters... If it needs to be closed, it's for being unclear.

Comment: @ZoharPeled the topic/title was the determining factor for me

Comment: @MichaelRandall well, I've voted to close as unclear, hopefully the OP will edit the post to include an actual question before it gets closed.

Comment: "got running time error" - usually those errors have, you know, *useful information in the error message*. You've not told us *what error you're getting*.

Comment: Why are you sending dates as strings to the database? Though I can't be sure without seeing the error message, and even if it's not the reason for your error, you shouldn't do that. Send dates as dates (instances of the DateTime struct) and not as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid SQL injections, another approach besides parametrized queries is stored procedures.

You can read it from here => https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/procedures.php
or you can research on your own.

Demo way of calling a stored procedure in an ASP.NET application:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Customers_GetCustomer", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustId", customerId);

        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

(Code taken from https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-MySql-Stored-Procedure-with-Parameters-in-ASPNet-C-and-VBNet.aspx)